# Indesign preflight not showing errors with cyrillic characters

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I'm laying out a document that's a couple hundred pages with several hundred footnotes. In some of the footnotes there are other languages such as Chinese, Russian, and Greek.

I've imported the document, but none of the foreign languages are displaying correctly. They're highlighted in pink with the character itself shown as a box. I know I could easily fix this by changing the font, but I don't know how to find instances of this. The preflight panel shows no errors despite the pink highlighting.

Can anyone help me search for all instances of the pink highlighter in my document? Due to the number of footnotes I cannot reasonably search page-by-page.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a bit late for you now, but the easiest way to fix that is to add a GREP style (or do a GREP find-and-replace to manually add a character style) on all characters within the Greek/Cyrillic/CJK Unicode ranges. There’s an InDesignSecrets article about how to target Unicode ranges in GREP queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as per your edit, you can customize what the preflight will or will not mark as an error, via prefligh profiles:

- https://indesignsecrets.com/customizing-a-preflight-profile.php
- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/preflighting-files-handoff.html